# Merge one branch to another if first branch created from parent of second

Tags: git, merge

I have branch 'master'.

I have branch 'develop' that was created from 'master'.

I noticed a critical bug on my site, I created a branch 'fix' from branch 'master'. Made some fix.

Now, I want to merge 'fix' into 'develop' to test it on develop server, and if everything ok - merge 'fix' to 'master'. But when I merge 'fix' into 'develop' git says that everything up to date, but changes doesn't appear in 'develop'. Why?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you're talking about? I think I may know the issue, but I need to see something.

Comment: If you are doing this on a remote server, did you do a `git pull` and then `merge` ? If not, after you `merge`, please make sure you `push`

Comment: Strange.. I did git pull, but I made it again after your comment and now everything ok.